# CSS dynamic font-size according to text length

Tags: css

I have a fixed-sized DIV block, and I don't know its text content lenght.
I would like to fit the font-size with the block size.

[image]

Please mind: I don't want to change font size according to the container size (`font-size: 1vh;`), but I want to change font size according to text lenght.

Comment: you need to use javascript to do this .

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20968345/2827823), with that you can easily make this work, it use script though, as their is not yet a css only solution.